# Regular expression for commonly understandable number formats

Tags: regex

What is a regex that can match a generally understandable number?  (the simpler the better)

for example, it should match:

```
10
10.0
10.00
3.3333
123456
100,000
1,234,567
33,456.22
-2.2
.2
-.2
+.2
0.2
.20
```

should not match:

```
33,33.1
1.2.3
100,000,000000
```

Comment: What about 10.000.000,00? Many regions do numbers this way.

Comment: I would go for a parser (as in YACC), not only a regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
^[+-]?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+|(?:\d*|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)\.\d+)$
```

should catch most cases.

Explanation:

```
^                      # start of string
[+-]?                  # optional sign
(?:                    # match either...

 \d+                   # only digits
 |                     # or

 \d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+    # only comma-separated digits
 |                     # or

 (?:                   # either...
  \d*                  # only digits (optional)
  |                    # or
  \d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+   # comma-separated digits
 )                     # followed by...
 \.\d+                 # a dot and digits.

)                      # end of alternation
$                      # end of string.
```

Comment: It doesn't catch /^[+-]?(?:\d+|\d*\.\d+|\d{1,2}(?:,\d{3})+\.?\d*)$/.test('100,000,000,000')

Comment: It matches `100,00,0000` or `0,0,0,0` or `00`

Comment: No, it doesn't. What makes you think it does?

Comment: I probably tested with the old one. My bad. The only problem I can find is that it also matches `100,000000`.

Answer (score 1):

For the English style `DD,DDD.DD`:

```
^[+-]?(([1-9]\d{0,2})(([,]\d{3})*|\d*)([.]\d+)?|0?([.]\d+)|0)$
```

For both `DD,DDD.DD` and `DD.DDD,DD`

```
^[+-]?(([1-9]\d{0,2})(([,]\d{3})*|\d*)([.]\d+)?|0?([.]\d+)|([1-9]\d{0,2})(([.]\d{3})*|\d*)([,]\d+)?|0?([,]\d+)|0)$
```

[Here is how it works](http://tinyurl.com/38xfwet)

Hope I didn't miss anything. Please say if you find examples that don't work.

Comment: 1,1 and 1,11 are valid in other locales. Mine for example

Comment: `100,000,000000` no longer validates in the long version.