# Can one regular expression extract several number formats with surrounding text?

Tags: regex

Here is my problem. And the suggested conversation here very closely answers my question, but I still need help getting a few tweaks to it.

[Regular expression for commonly understandable number formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025845/regular-expression-for-commonly-understandable-number-formats)

Can one regular expression achieve this?

string :

```
texta wordb 1234 wordc textd
texta wordb $1234 wordc textd
texta wordb 1,234 wordc textd
texta wordb 1234.12 wordc textd
```

If this is one giant string above.  I want to extract to an array the [word before the number] + [the number] and [the word after the number], like so:

```
wordb 1234 wordc
wordb $1234 wordc
wordb 1,234 wordc
wordb 1234.12 wordc
```

Comment: Which language/tool are you working with?

Comment: regexes tend to be hard enough to read as they are. Why not have multiple regular expressions, each of which does exactly one thing?

Comment: Will, this is quite a trivial use case for regular expressions. No need to overcomplicate things.

Comment: m.buettner  I can use either Java or Python.  I tried using some NLP stuff, but it seems to be over complicating what should be a relatively easy task.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can:

```
(\p{L}+)\s([\d$,.]+)\s(\p{L}+)
```

or, more simply, but probably with wider support:

```
([a-zA-Z]+)\s([\d$,.]+)\s([a-zA-Z]+)
```

This essentially grabs a bunch of letters, then some whitespace, then a number which may also contain the characters $, comma and dot (expand if necessary, depending on what you expect) and another bunch of letters again.

If you don't need the individual parts you can get rid of the parentheses and just take the complete match. Otherwise the parts you want are in groups 1–3.

Quick PowerShell test:

```
PS> $re = '(\p{L}+)\s([\d$,.]+)\s(\p{L}+)'
PS> $tests = 'texta wordb 1234 wordc textd
>> texta wordb $1234 wordc textd
>> texta wordb 1,234 wordc textd
>> texta wordb 1234.12 wordc textd' -split "`n"
>>
PS> $tests | %{ $null = $_ -match $re; Write-Host Word 1: $Matches[1], Number: $Matches[2], Word 2: $Matches[3] }
Word 1: wordb Number: 1234 Word 2: wordc
Word 1: wordb Number: $1234 Word 2: wordc
Word 1: wordb Number: 1,234 Word 2: wordc
Word 1: wordb Number: 1234.12 Word 2: wordc
```

Comment: You need some repetition quantifier for the character class.